# RestSharp 422 response

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I am experiencing very strange behavior with one particular API. I am posting some data and getting normal response in Postman and in cUrl, but getting 422 response using RestSharp.

Here is my JSON I am trying to send:

```
{
  "sale": [
    {
      "external_id": "",
      "sold_at": "01/15/2018",
      "sold_to": "anonymous",
      "discount_total": "0.00",
      "price_total": "0.00",
      "tax_total": "0.00",
      "reason": "",
      "status": "sale",
      "cog_total": "0.00",
      "global_sold_by_user_id": "WASTATE1.US2I9",
      "global_area_id": "WAGAG2.ARASF",
      "global_customer_id": "",
      "sale_items": [
        {
          "external_id": "",
          "use_by_date": "01/15/2018",
          "description": "HOC-Do Si Do 1G Package",
          "type": "marijuana",
          "sold_at": "01/15/2018",
          "qty": "1.000000",
          "uom": "gm",
          "unit_price": "55.000000",
          "discount_total": "0.00",
          "price_total": "0.00",
          "tax_total": "0.00",
          "potency": "",
          "returned_reason": "",
          "returned_at": "",
          "total_marijuana_in_grams": "1.000000000000",
          "name": "",
          "unit_cog": "0.00",
          "global_customer_id": "",
          "global_batch_id": "WAGAG2.BA32H",
          "global_returned_by_user_id": "",
          "global_inventory_id": "WAG2.IN171",
          "sale_item_taxes": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my code snippet:

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://watest.leafdatazone.com");
            var request = new RestRequest(args.Path, args.IsPost ? Method.POST : Method.GET);

            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("x-mjf-mme-code", "<my_code>");
            request.AddHeader("x-mjf-key", "<my_key>");
            if (args.IsPost)
            {
                request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", args.RequestJSON, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            }

            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any ideas what might be going on? I have tried HttpClient as well with the same results. Same exact JSON with same exact headers works fine in Postman. I even used code snippet from Postman in my code and example here, still with 422.

Comment: inspect and compare the raw requests to see what differences may be causing the isse

Comment: Also try removing the `charset` and see if that helps

Comment: This may give you some input: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/818931/how-to-increase-restsharp-response-size-limitaiton